# Windows 7 x64 bit deployment using SCCM 2007

Tags: deployment, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, sccm, sccm-2007

I have some difficulties regarding deploying Windows 7 x64 bits using SCCM2007.

When the PC gets rebooted it does not show the option to process with Windows 7 x64, I already have x86 version and it comes up with only x86 bits.

Can anyone suggest me how to troubleshoot? or if anyone has a check list so I can check if I did everything correctly.

Many thanks

Daff0dil

Comment: I have an a copy of windows 7x64 bit. I added the Win7DVD as the Reference OS image to the configuration manager and deployed to 
the PXE distribution point. Then added the distribution point to the new OS package. I made sure the package is installed.

Comment: after that i installed configuration manager client package and also added distribution points to this package. Later I developed the task sequence to deploy the OS.

Comment: Later I advertised the Win7Deployment task to Test collection and made it available to PXE service point